# "service" not showing up

Tags: services, launch-services

I installed the  GlobalProtect VPN on MacOS Darwin 18.7

I cannot remove it. It is attempting to start but does not succeed.
It appears in the output of

```
ps aux

518   5.6  0.3  6093596 112332   ??  S     5:00PM   1:40.86 /Applications/GlobalProtect.app/Contents/MacOS/GlobalProtect
```

I wonder why it is not showing up in:

```
launchctl list
```

eventhough it restart automatically at reboot.

Thank you

Comment: Darwin 18.7 == macOS 10.14.6 I presume?

Comment: In `launchctl list` it should show up as `com.paloaltonetworks.gp.pangps` and `com.paloaltonetworks.gp.pangpa`.

Comment: I ended up using Big IP Edge client, accessing an F5